# How to tag several changeset in sqlfile mode

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I use sqlfile mode.
in a sql file I wrote severals changeset :

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset chs:31 
create table tab_tst3(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);
--rollback drop table tab_tst3;

--changeset chs:32 
insert into tab_tst3 (id, name) values (1, 'tab 1');
insert into tab_tst3 (id, name) values (2, 'tab 2');

--changeset chs:33
create sequence tab_seq3;
--rollback drop sequence tab_seq3;
```

when i execute that file like :

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx--username=xxx--
password=xxx --changeLogFile=myfile.sql
```

Starting Liquibase at jeu., 08 ao¹t 2019 15:48:14 CEST (version 3.7.0 built at 2019-07-16 02:26:39)
Successfully tagged 'xxxx'

And when I  do

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx--username=xxx--
password=xxx --tag=myTAG
```

Only the last ligne is tagged (chs:33)

How to tag all the 3 lines with the same tag ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What the tag command does is mark a particular set of changes that have been deployed already as "this set of changes is in a good state that I might want to get back to". So the idea is that you ran `liquibase update` and the three changesets in the changelog at that time get deployed to the database. You do some testing, and you decide that everything is good, so you run `liquibase tag` to mark that spot. You continue development, and add some new changesets, and use `liquibase update` to deploy those to the database. During your testing, you discover a problem, so you want to go back to the last known good state, so you use the `liquibase rollback` command with the tag you applied and it rolls back the newer changes that were problematic, getting you back to a known good state.